# Multi threaded lambda function (AWS) is taking drastically high time to compute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Problem : Fetch 2000 items from Dynamo DB and process it batch by batch (Batch size = 100).

What I've tried : I've configured a cron schedule to run my Lambda function. I'm using Java. I've made multi-threaded application which synchronously does so.

Query : My computation time has been drastically increased. Even If I sum up the time required by individual thread theoretically, then it comes much lowers than the actual time required to run my lambda function. Any help on this? Or way to reduce the time.

PS : The same multi threaded application on my local box is taking much lower time to execute.

Comment: I abandoned Lambdas for computationally intense activities for just this reason - you just can't get good throughput with a single instance. If you split your code into 20 Lambdas (i.e. one per batch) you'd likely see the throughput you want.  Have you tried your code on a t2.nano EC2 instance?  Those are fairly cheap (~USD $5/month) but I don't know that they would be fast enough for your use case.

Comment: Ya, plus 1 on what @stdunbar said, anything you have a fear of timing out on should not be in a Lambda, rather an Ec2 instance with maybe a queue poller and you can add work items to the queue with a lambda

Comment: I want to do it once daily, this job will take hardly an hour to complete. If I'll create EC2 instance than it would be running all the day. Plus, I have to manage the listener to an event, which I am getting in lambda by AWS.

Comment: What event are you watching?  The cron schedule could use a fairly simple "aws ec2" script to start an instance, run a cloud-init script to install your software, run what you need and, as the last step in your processing, terminate the instance.  You could adjust the instance size and power to meet your requirements and minimize cost.